# Slow MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to figure out why the site I am working on (Laravel 4.2 framework) is really slow at times, and I think it has to do with my database setup. I am not a pro at all so I would assume that where the problem is

My `sessions` table has roughly 2.2 million records in it, when I run `show processlist;`, all the queries that take the longest relate to that table.

Here is a picture for example:

[image]

Table structure

[image]

Surerly I am doing something wrong or it's not index properly? I'm not sure, not fantastic with databases.

Comment: Your best bet is to ditch database sessions and store them in something like Redis. Database sessions are simply not suitable for high traffic - you get exactly this sort of write contention on the sessions table.

Comment: Do you ever clear that table and remove "dead" sessions?

Answer (score 1):

We don't see the complete SQL being executed, so we can't recommend appropriate indexes. But if the only predicate on the DELETE statements is on the `last_activity` column i.e.

```
DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE last_activity <= 'somevalue' ;
```

Then performance of the DELETE statement will likely be improved by adding an index with a leading column of `somevalue`, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX sessions_IX1 ON sessions (last_activity);
```

Also, if this table is using MyISAM storage engine, then DML statements cannot execute concurrently; DML statements will block while waiting to obtain exclusive lock on the table. The InnoDB storage engine uses row level locking, so some DML operations can be concurrent. (InnoDB doesn't eliminate lock contention, but locks will be on rows and index blocks, rather than on the entire table.)

---

Also consider using a different storage mechanism (other than MySQL database) for storing and retrieving info for web server "sessions".

Also, is it necessary (is there some requirement) to persist 2.2 million "sessions" rows? Are we sure that all of those rows are actually needed?  If some of that data is historical, and isn't specifically needed to support the current web server sessions, we might consider moving the historical data to another table.